# AddThis new trending box, how to remove the extra Hashtags added to the URL's

Tags: hashtag, addthis

AddThis new trending box, how to remove the extra Hashtags added to the URL's by AddThis.

Exemple: http://www.website.co.uk/#at_pco=tcb-1.0&at_tot=5&at_ab=-&at_pos=3

https://www.addthis.com/get/trending

Answer (score 1):

The hashtags at the end of the URL are used to track and report how many clicks you get.  If you're using AddThis analytics, you'll want to leave them.  However, if you're not using AddThis analytics, you can disable the hashes by setting "tag" to false like this:

```
addthis.box("#addthis_trendingcontent", {
    tag: false
});
```

All the options for the trending content box can be found here:

http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/521730-trending-content-box-api#.Uu0mg3ddWTM

Comment: I did add this tag: false but I'm still getting all the extra hashtags  seem to be a bug. Here the code I'm using: addthis.box("#addthis_trendingcontent", {
        feed_title : "",
        feed_type : "trending",
        feed_period : "month",
        num_links : 5,
        height : "auto",
        width : "auto",
        tag : false});